# How to select between 3 or more widget on flutter

Tags: flutter, if-statement, dart, switch-statement

I am trying to choose a widget or result between 3 according to the selected enum using a switch or if statement but it gives me an error

`Text(if (selectedLang==Lang.English){ 'Hello World } else if (selectedLang==Lang.Lang.Turkish){ 'Mehaba dunya' } else { 'Hallo Wereld' } )`

Comment: am not looking for using methods it would be such a long way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out this way

```
child: Text(
            selectedLang == Lang.English
               ? 'Hello Wrold'
               : selectedLang == Lang.Turkish
                  ? 'Mehaba dunya'
                  :'Hallo Wereld'
           ),
```

[image]